# Align text to a circle / curved path

Tags: qml, gauge

I'm making a vehicle's instrument cluster in QML and wanted to align the speed labels to the curve in such a way that they are all the same distance away from it. To do this, I used `pathview` to set up an arc, then used the `text` delegate to have the text appear in the right places. The reason it's not working exactly as intended is that some text is larger than other (for example '0' takes less space than '100') which causes some variability in distance between the text and the circle I'm trying to align it with. How can this be done better?

Here's the snippet of what I have got working so far:

```
Component {
    id: spdLabel
    Text {
        font.weight: Font.Normal
        font.pixelSize: 28
        color: "white"
        text: model.index
        visible: model.index % spdMarkInterval == 0
    }
}

PathView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    z: 0
    model: topSpeed + 1
    delegate: spdLabel
    path: Path {
        PathAngleArc {
            centerX: (dialGauge.x + dialGauge.width)/2
            centerY: (dialGauge.y + dialGauge.height)/2
            radiusX: 140
            radiusY: 140
            sweepAngle: 270
            startAngle: 135
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]

Since it is the center of text elements that's anchored a constant distance away from the arc, the distance between the text edge and arc varies.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what are `dialGauge` and `topSpeed `? can you please provide [mcve] so we can test the code?

Comment: `topSpeed` is literally just that, top speed, which in this case is 120.
`spdMarkInterval` is the interval by which the gradations differ, which here is 10.
`dialGauge` is the needle (I should prolly have named it just that). That's where the  `PathAngleArc` that generates the text items is centered.

Comment: have you tried putting the text inside an Item?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have not. I can try but I don't see how that might help...

Comment: Item has no implicit sizing... BTW if you use plain rectangles would it align perfectly?

Comment: @TOHO Doesn't work with Item and no implicit size, [here's the result](https://imgur.com/znrIsrs).
With circles that are all the same size, [it works just fine](https://imgur.com/nYlGWOv).

Comment: since you cant control the text width and height only by setting font sizes i can think of two solutions 1. use images instead text and provide the source in your model, 2. calculate somehow the exact offset by the text length and move the items x,y correspondingly.